# How to find out if user is moving in a vehicle in iOS when there is no M7 Processor in iOS Device?

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager, core-motion, cmmotionmanager

I know how to find out if user is moving in a vehicle in the following cases:

**1. CLLocationManager**:

In this case, based on the speed in `locationManager:didUpdateLocations` method i can find out if user is moving in vehicle.

**2. If M7 Is available --> CMMotionActivityManager**:

In this case, i can make use of `CMMotionActivity` in `startActivityUpdatesToQueue:withHandler` method and find out if user is moving in vehicle.

I'm stuck in the case where **iOS Device doesn't have M7 Processor**.

I can use `CLLocationManager` in this case, but it is draining device battery, So I'm not going to choose this option to achieve the functionality.

Please provide me guidelines to find out if user is moving in a vehicle **If M7 Is not available**.

I have referred the following links, But They didn't help me.

- [Detecting if a user is moving in a car](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17869659/detecting-if-a-user-is-moving-in-a-car)
- [Utilizing the M7 chip in the iPhone5S](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19640151/utilizing-the-m7-chip-in-the-iphone5s)
- [Use similar technology as CMMotionActivity on older iPhones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19337307/use-similar-technology-as-cmmotionactivity-on-older-iphones)

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hi, i have the exact same problem, did you find the answer?

Comment: @ozd. Not yet. Actually I was not able to spend more time on it as I had other things on priority. Check this once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17869659/detecting-if-a-user-is-moving-in-a-car

Comment: I strongly suggest to adopt new frameworks and APIs.